# Django Ajax Search does not retern anything

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, search

I have implemented follow this video but I got nothing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY

These are my code
in my template, I try to include the java script in main html file

```
    <h3>SEARCH</h3>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
    <ul id="search-result">

    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/projects/search/",
                    data:{
                        'search_text':$('#search').val(),
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                    },
                    success: searchSuccess,
                    dataType:'html'
                });
            });
        });
        function searchSuccess(data,textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            $('#search-results'.html(data));
        }

    </script>
```

projects models.py

```
class projects(models.Model):

    project_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=" ", max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name=" ", max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='', auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True,
    help_text="")
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='', null=True, blank=True,
    help_text="")
    end_date   = models.DateField(verbose_name='', null=True, blank=True,help_text="")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return u"%s" % (self.project_name)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^search/$',search_titles),
```

view.py in projects app and ajax_search.html is in the same directory as main html

```
def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''
    pros = projects.objects.filter(id=search_text)
    return render_to_response('front/ajax_search.html',{'pros':pros})
```

ajax_search.html

```
{% if pros.count>0 %}
{% for pro in pros %}
    <li>
        {{ pro.project_name }}
   </li>

{% endfor %}
{% else %}
 <li>
    NO!!
 </li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in `ajax_search.html` template.  You should add spaces around `<`:

```
{% if pros.count > 0 %}
```

But anyway this template is not very djangoish.  Consider to use [for ... empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) syntax:

```
{% for pro in pros %}
    <li>{{ pro.project_name }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>NO!!</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**:  What do you mean in this line?

```
pros = projects.objects.filter(id=search_text)
```

I doubt that you want to search for `id`.  Change it to:

```
pros = projects.objects.filter(project_name=search_text)
```

or even to:

```
pros = projects.objects.filter(project_name__icontains=search_text)
```

Comment: follow your suggestion, the output still nothing

Comment: I quite doubt that ajax is not work or I implement something wrong .